# Difference between pandas aggregators .first() and .last()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregation, pandas-resample

I'm curious as to what `last()` and `first()` does in this specific instance (when chained to a resampling). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand if you pass arguments into first and last, e.g. 3; it returns the first 3 months or first 3 years.

In this circumstance, since I'm not passing any arguments into `first()` and `last()`, what is it actually doing when I'm resampling it like that? I know that if I resample by chaining `.mean()`, I'll resample into years with the mean score from averaging all the months, but what is happening when I'm using `last()`?

More importantly, why does `first()` and `last()` give me different answers in this context? I see that numerically they are not equal.

i.e: `post2008.resample().first() != post2008.resample().last()`

TLDR:

1. What does `.first()` and `.last()` do?
2. What does `.first()` and `.last()` do in this instance, when chained to a resample?
3. Why does `.resample().first() != .resample().last()`?

This is the code before the aggregation:

```py
# Read 'GDP.csv' into a DataFrame: gdp
gdp = pd.read_csv('GDP.csv', index_col='DATE', parse_dates=True)

# Slice all the gdp data from 2008 onward: post2008
post2008 = gdp.loc['2008-01-01':,:]

# Print the last 8 rows of post2008
print(post2008.tail(8))
```

This is what `print(post2008.tail(8))` outputs:

```
              VALUE
DATE               
2014-07-01  17569.4
2014-10-01  17692.2
2015-01-01  17783.6
2015-04-01  17998.3
2015-07-01  18141.9
2015-10-01  18222.8
2016-01-01  18281.6
2016-04-01  18436.5
```

Here is the code that resamples and aggregates by `last()`:

```py
# Resample post2008 by year, keeping last(): yearly
yearly = post2008.resample('A').last()
print(yearly)
```

This is what yearly is like when it's `post2008.resample('A').last()`:

```
              VALUE
DATE               
2008-12-31  14549.9
2009-12-31  14566.5
2010-12-31  15230.2
2011-12-31  15785.3
2012-12-31  16297.3
2013-12-31  16999.9
2014-12-31  17692.2
2015-12-31  18222.8
2016-12-31  18436.5
```

Here is the code that resamples and aggregates by `first()`:

```py
# Resample post2008 by year, keeping first(): yearly
yearly = post2008.resample('A').first()
print(yearly)
```

This is what yearly is like when it's `post2008.resample('A').first()`:

```
            VALUE
DATE               
2008-12-31  14668.4
2009-12-31  14383.9
2010-12-31  14681.1
2011-12-31  15238.4
2012-12-31  15973.9
2013-12-31  16475.4
2014-12-31  17025.2
2015-12-31  17783.6
2016-12-31  18281.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Before anything else, let's create a dataframe with example data:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2014-07-01', '2014-10-01', '2015-01-01',
                            '2015-04-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-07-01',
                            '2016-01-01', '2016-04-01'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE': range(1000, 9000, 1000)}, index=dates)
print(df)
```

The output will be

```
            VALUE
2014-07-01   1000
2014-10-01   2000
2015-01-01   3000
2015-04-01   4000
2015-07-01   5000
2015-07-01   6000
2016-01-01   7000
2016-04-01   8000
```

If we pass e.g. `'6M'` to `df.first` (which is not an aggregator, but a [DataFrame method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html)), we will be selecting the first six months of data, which in the example above consists of just two days:

```
print(df.first('6M'))
```

```
            VALUE
2014-07-01   1000
2014-10-01   2000
```

Similarly, [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) returns only the rows that belong to the last six months of data:

```
print(df.last('6M'))
```

```
            VALUE
2016-01-01   6000
2016-04-01   7000
```

In this context, not passing the required argument results in an error:

```
print(df.first())
```

> TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'

On the other hand, `df.resample('Y')` returns a [Resampler object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/resampling.html), which has aggregation methods [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html), [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.last.html), [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.mean.html), etc. In this case, they keep only the first (respectively, last) values of each year (instead of e.g. averaging all values, or some other kind of aggregation):

```
print(df.resample('Y').first())
```

```
            VALUE
2014-12-31   1000
2015-12-31   3000  # This is the first of the 4 values from 2015
2016-12-31   7000
```

```
print(df.resample('Y').last())
```

```
            VALUE
2014-12-31   2000
2015-12-31   6000  # This is the last of the 4 values from 2015
2016-12-31   8000
```

As an extra example, consider also the case of grouping by a smaller period:

```
print(df.resample('M').last().head())
```

```
             VALUE
2014-07-31  1000.0  # This is the last (and only) value from July, 2014
2014-08-31     NaN  # No data for August, 2014
2014-09-30     NaN  # No data for September, 2014
2014-10-31  2000.0
2014-11-30     NaN  # No data for November, 2014
```

In this case, any periods for which there is no value will be filled with NaNs. Also, for this example, using `first` instead of `last` would have returned the same values, since each month has (at most) one value.

Comment: thank you for this example and explanation!

some minor correction of the answer above:   
for the `resample('Y').first -> last value should be 7000`, 
for the `resample('Y').last -> last value should be 8000`